# jQuery countdown - apply to new elements loaded via AJAX / PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a container div which loops through items in a PHP array to generate repeating element divs all with a unique ID.

I am using a countdown plugin (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to apply to a date on each element and it worked out in PHP.

This all works fine until I load more elements into the page using AJAX /PHP.  The countdown isn't applied to the new items and I am struggling to figure out how I would do this.

```
echo "<div class=\"item\" id=\"item_$id\">
<h4 class=\"name\">$Name</h4>
<p>$Cat</p>";
if ($expires != '') {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($discount['expires']));
    $month = date('n', strtotime($discount['expires']));
    $day = date('d', strtotime($discount['expires']));
    $hour = date('H', strtotime($discount['expires']));
    $minute = date('i', strtotime($discount['expires']));
    $secs = date('s', strtotime($discount['expires']));
    $countdown_html = '<div class="defaultCountdown" id="countdown_' . $id . '" data-year="'. $year .'"  data-month="'. $month .'" data-day="'. $day .'" data-hour="'. $hour .'" data-minute="'. $minute .'" data-secs="'. $secs .'"></div>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $(window).load(function(){
        var year = $('#countdown_$id').attr('data-year');
        var month = $('#countdown_$id').attr('data-month');
        var day = $('#countdown_$id').attr('data-day');
        var hour = $('#countdown_$id').attr('data-hour');   
        var minute = $('#countdown_$id').attr('data-minute'); 
        var secs = $('#countdown_$id').attr('data-secs');     
        $('#countdown_$id').countdown({until: new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, secs)});
    });
</script>";
}
echo "</div>\n";
}

function loadMoreItems(getQuery, page) {
    //load items
    $.get(getQuery, null, function(data) {
    var container = $(data).find('#container');
    if (container) {
        var newItemsHTML = "";
        newItemsHTML = $(container).html();
        var $newItems = $(newItemsHTML);
        $container.isotope('insert', $newItems, true);
        //add jquery effects to new elements 
        $newItems.find('.hcaption').hcaptions({effect: "fade"});
        $newItems.find(".live-tile").liveTile({pauseOnHover: true});
        $('.defaultCountdown').each( function() {
            var year = $(this).attr('data-year');
            var month = $(this).attr('data-month');
            var day = $(this).attr('data-day');
            var hour = $(this).attr('data-hour');
            var minute = $(this).attr('data-minute');
            var secs = $(this).attr('data-secs');
            $('#' + this.id).countdown({until: new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, secs)});
        });
    }
}, 'html');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your ajax function returns, just call the jquery to initialise the countdowns again.

Instead of using php to echo the values into the jQuery call - add them to the div itself, e.g

```
<div class="defaultCountdown" data-year="2013" data-month="11">
```

Then to initialise it would be:

```
$('div.defaultCountdown').each( function() )
{
year = $(this).attr('year');
...
$(this).countdown({until: new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, secs)});
});
```

Add some way of checking if an element has already been processed.  You could create the elements initially with class="unprocessed"

```
<div class="defaultCountdown unprocessed">
```

The countdown initialise function would then be:

```
$('div.defaultCountdown.unprocessed').each(function(){...})
```

After the countdown has been initialised remove the 'unprocessed' class name

Comment: OK, but then how do I add the countdown to the unprocessed ones?  How do I add the correct date to the unprocessed ones?

Comment: I edit the answer, hadn't seen the jquery code that started the countdowns

Comment: To set the correct date, add the date values in the div

so <div class=defaultCountdown" data-year="2013" data-month="12"> etc

And modify the countdown call to get the data from the div's attributes

Comment: OK, Ive made the changes you suggest, but still no joy.  Edited code above.

Comment: $container.isotope('insert', $newItems, true);

Should this be $('#container').isotope('insert', $newItems, true); ?

Comment: I have: var $container = $('#container') further up the page

Comment: But $container.isotope isn't a valid variable, should just be container

And container is being set to  var container = $(data).find('#container');

Which is just an object made from your data, but it's not attached to your DOM

Comment: Im not sure how that would make a difference.  Im sorry Im not understanding what I need to do to get this working

Comment: Ok, I needed to add $newItems.find before the hcaptions selector and move the $container.isotope underneath that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".element").each(function() { 
    var item_id = "#" + this.id;
    if(this.id != 'discount_0'){
       container.find(discount_id).remove(); 
    }
    $(element_id).countdown({until: new Date($year, $month - 1, $day, $hour, $minute, $secs)});
   });
```

when you are applying countdown you are calling on `$(element_id)`, it should be

```
$(item_id)
```

and you are using `$year, $month - 1, $day, $hour, $minute, $secs` all these are php variables,you cannot use them as jquery variables